# Calculate the matrix of a linear opertor that transforms a vector to a Hankel matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, linear-transformations

I would like to calculate the matrix associated to a linear operator $\mathbf{R}$ that transforms a vector $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^N$ into a Hankel matrix $\mathbf{H}\in\mathbb{R}^{N-Q+1\times Q}$ where $Q$ is a given integer, that is,
$$
\mathbf{H} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x(1) & x(2) & x(3) & \cdots & x(Q)\\
x(2) & x(3) & x(4) & \cdots & x(Q+1)\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
x(N-Q) & x(N-Q+1) & x(N-Q+2) & \cdots & x(N-1)\\
x(N-Q+1) & x(N-Q+2) & x(N-Q+3) & \cdots & x(N)
\end{bmatrix}
= \mathbf{Rx}.
$$

Someone told me that this linear operator has associated a matrix but I do not know how could it be. Any idea or suggestion?
Thanks.